How can I configure my AKS cluster to only allow kubectl commands when connected to a specific Pritunl VPN
I want that when I am connected to my (Dev6) pritunl, I should be able to run kubectl commands on my AKS cluster and otherwise, I should not be able to.
I tried adding the specific IP range of my Dev6 pritunl to the AKS cluster "Authorized IP Range" section under Public Access, but it is making my dev6 down.
I also tried adding a NSG to one of my subnet allowing traffic to the specific IP range, but that also didn't work.

For the --api-server-authorized-ip-ranges parameter, are you trying to use a private IP address range? If so then update the AKS cluster to only allow access from the Dev6 VPN IP range. For example-
az aks update --resource-group arkorg --name timezone --api-server-authorized-ip-ranges 10.10.10.0/24

and if its a public IP range, you can directly specify that public IP range in the --api-server-authorized-ip-ranges.
az aks update --resource-group arkorg --name timezone --api-server-authorized-ip-ranges <public-ip-address-or-range>


Basically in order to use the --api-server-authorized-ip-ranges parameter, you'll need to specify a valid public IP address or range. If your VPN uses private IP addresses, consider using a private AKS cluster where the API server is only accessible within the VNet, which can be integrated with your VPN for secure access

Obtain the public IP address that your Pritunl VPN server uses for outbound connections. This is the IP that will be seen by the Azure API server. az aks update --resource-group arkorg --name pritunl-cluster --api-server-authorized-ip-ranges 

My pritunl is running on a azure VM and I tried to add the public IP of that VM in the specified IP range of the AKS Cluster and that worked like a charm. But the problem is now scaling is being compromised for my nodes, scaling is not happening.

I think that is due to the AKS cluster's API server needing to communicate with various Azure services for scaling operations. When you limit access to a single IP address (like your Pritunl VM's public IP), you might inadvertently block the necessary communication required for AKS to manage scaling operations. I think if you update the AKS API server with a combination of your Pritunl VM's public IP and the necessary Azure IP ranges, it should fix the issue.

Give it a try- az aks update --resource-group arkorg --name pritunl-cluster --api-server-authorized-ip-ranges ,,,...
After updating the authorized IP ranges, test the scaling operation by manually scaling the nodes

I think I was able to solve the issue by adding the internal IP range of my AKS cluster nodes along with the public IP of the vm.

Updating the same as answer what we discussed over chat. Feel free to add any additional points.
In order to configure your AKS cluster to only allow kubectl commands when connected to your Pritunl VPN (Dev6), while still ensuring that node scaling is not compromised, first, make sure you have the public IP address of the Azure VM where your Pritunl VPN server is running. This public IP will be used to restrict access to the AKS API server.
Use the --api-server-authorized-ip-ranges parameter to update your AKS cluster to only allow access from the public IP of your Pritunl VM using-
az aks update --resource-group arkorg --name arkoaks --api-server-authorized-ip-ranges <pritunl-public-ip>

As you saw, restricting access to only your VPN's public IP is interfering with scaling operations, you should also include the Azure IP ranges using-
az aks update --resource-group arkorg --name arkoaks --api-server-authorized-ip-ranges <pritunl-public-ip>,<azure-ip-range-1>,<azure-ip-range-2>,...

Reference-
Azure IP Ranges and Service Tags
API server authorized IP ranges
Similar SO thread

Yes, i was able to do this. But now there are many issues like sometimes scaling suffers or my pods are not able to communicate to the API server. For this, we are trying to update our AKS cluster to a private cluster. Do you have any insights regarding this?
As it is written on internet that we cannot convert an existing AKS cluster into a private one.

Actually i was able to convert it into private: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/api-server-vnet-integration#enable-private-cluster-mode

Fantastic, thanks for the document link
